# How to get from Prague to Punkva caves and Macocha abyss?

Tags: public-transport, car-rentals, day-trips, czech-republic, prague

On my next trip to Prague I would like to visit the Punkva caves and Macocha abyss. Can I get there by public transport or is it better to rent a car from Prague?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By public transport it's little harder to get there, but yes, it is possible:

1) Go to **Brno** first. The easiest and most comfortable is by *bus* with the company [Student Agency](http://www.studentagency.eu/) (it's very popular transport - I recommend to buy a ticket in advance - you can do it online)

2) **Brno** to **Blansko** by *train* and **Blansko** to **Punkva caves** by *bus*

Search departures on [jizdnirady.cz](http://jizdnirady.idnes.cz/idsjmk/spojeni/) (there is English version)

Fill in:

```
  Timetable: JMK Public Transport
  From:      Brno 
  To:        Blansko, Skalní Mlýn
```

and enjoy beauties of Czech Republic! :)

Comment: There are also direct trains from Prague to Blansko; this might be slightly cheaper than the above. You may then want to take a bus from the train station, or take a walk (a few km). Try the "Trains+Buses+Public transport" timetable at jizdnirady.cz - this will find both options, mine and @Lex Vjatkin's.